# Как установить только несколько компонентов jsxgraph?

Tags: node.js, jsx

Офф. сайт `JSXGraph`: [ссылка](https://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/index.html)
npm-пакет: [ссылка](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsxgraph)

Я использую `NodeJS`, и я бы хотел использовать только несколько компонентов `JSXGraph`, а не все! Поэтому использовать `cdnjs` не вариант.

Другими словами, мне нужно иметь свою личную сборку `JSXGraph` (потому что в своём приложении я не нуждаюсь в таком свойстве, как «lastDragTime: Sat Oct 13 2018 22:17:36 GMT + ...»)

Как я могу установить только несколько компонентов `JSXGraph`? И какой файл нужно добавить в качестве основного скрипта в `HTML`?

(Я использую Windows)